# How to edit request in python to add TLS settings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, python-requests, tls1.2

I need to edit the python request to add **TLS settings** (by **TLS settings** I mean tls finger printing int, ja3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JA3 fingerprint is based on ciphers and order and various TLS extensions and order. While ciphers and order can be changed features like the TLS extension order are not accessible from Python. This means there is no way to emulate a specific JA3 fingerprint from Python and thus also not from requests.

Comment: thanks for your answer !

Comment: So how do packages like requests-ja3 work? I thought thats exactly what it does

Comment: @West: Assuming you mean [this](https://github.com/an0ndev/requests-ja3). It clearly states *"experimental and not currently in a working state"*. But the approach tried here is not pure Python but instead to use its own bindings to the OpenSSL library because as I said *"... features like the TLS extension order are not accessible from Python"*. But again, right now there is no actual working code to imitate any JA3.

Comment: Right I see., got it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [curl_cffi](https://github.com/yifeikong/curl_cffi). Although you can not modify the TLS settings at python level, you can change them when using C extensions, such as curl.

```
pip install curl_cffi
```

It has a requests-like interface:

```py
from curl_cffi import requests

# Notice the impersonate parameter
r = requests.get("https://tls.browserleaks.com/json", impersonate="chrome101")

print(r.json())
# output: {'ja3_hash': '53ff64ddf993ca882b70e1c82af5da49'
# the fingerprint should be the same as target browser
```