# Is it possible to set a custom ja3 fingerprint using ssl context/requests package or httpx?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ive been trying to figure out how to set a custom fingerprint(ja3) into a request, I came across  [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70672970/how-to-edit-request-in-python-to-add-tls-settings). I'm just curious if its actually possible or not maybe with ctx.set_ciphers in the ssl package or something. The code already uses this; `ctx = ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change all the settings in python. Use libraries like [curl_cffi](https://github.com/yifeikong/curl_cffi) to edit this in C-level.